# How to add options to an argument of a slash command in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
import discord
from discord import app_commands

class aclient(discord.Client):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(intents=discord.Intents.default())
        self.synced = False

    async def on_ready(self):
        await self.wait_until_ready()
        if not self.synced:
            await tree.sync(guild=discord.Object(id=748244591387607111))
            self.synced = True
        print('---------------------Bot is ready---------------------')

client = aclient()
tree = app_commands.CommandTree(client)

@tree.command(name='test')
async def test(interaction: discord.Interaction, option: str):
    pass

client.run('MYTOKEN')
```

That's my code. I want to add an option where I can select between several categories, for example `test1` and `test2`. I don't want to use an external library like `pycord` or `nextcord`, I want to do it in the native `discord.py`. Not asking for any code, just an example of how I'd go about doing it. Everything I found online was either outdated or used `nextcord`, so I decided to ask here. Hope someone can help : )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example of how to specify options for a command parameter:

```py
@tree.command(name='test')
@app_commands.describe(option="This is a description of what the option means")
@app_commands.choices(option=[
        app_commands.Choice(name="Option 1", value="1"),
        app_commands.Choice(name="Option 2", value="2")
    ])
async def test(interaction: discord.Interaction, option: app_commands.Choice[str]):
    pass
```

To make the option optional, you'd have to `import typing` and change the type to:

```py
async def test(interaction: discord.Interaction, option: typing.Optional[app_commands.Choice[str]]):
    pass
```