# How to have a list of options you can choose from an argument within discord.py slash commands?

Tags: discord, discord.py

I want to achieve something like this but it is not possible:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6juP1.png)

I tried:

`@app_commands.option(name='name', description="Choose a name", choices=["Alice", "Bob", "James", "Charlie"])`

No solution.

Comment: Why don't you add something like `choice: typing.Literal['...', '...']` to your slash command directly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add options to an argument of a slash command in discord.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73686327/how-to-add-options-to-an-argument-of-a-slash-command-in-discord-py)

Answer (score 0):

You need `app_commands.choice`.

Code:

```
@bot.tree.command(name="choices")
@app_commands.choices(options = [
    app_commands.Choice(name="a",value="This is a"),
    app_commands.Choice(name="b",value="This is b")
])
async def choices(interaction:discord.Interaction,options:app_commands.Choice[str]):
    await interaction.response.send_message(f"{options.value}. You choose option {options.name}",ephemeral=True)
```

You can't use this properly without a `slash command`.
This code returns both the `value` and the `name` property of `options`.

You can name `options` variable anything but it has to match with the variable in the `async def...` line.

`ephemeral=True` is optional. It makes the response disappear for anybody other than the user who used the command.